# I can´t do a delete for do data union in a trigger update mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hello I have got a table named *example* in mysql with the next fields *a, b, c* al fields are varchar 255, and unique per column.

The unique restriction per column I do with a trigger before insert;

An example of table:

```
------------
a    b    c     
------------
a         c
     b
d    e
f         g
     h
          i
j
          k
     l    n
c
     a
```

This table is ok, because al values in each column are unique exception that ""

An example of wrog table

```
------------
a    b    c     
------------
a    b    c
     b
```

This table is wrong, because the field b have same value in two columns

I want to be able to do the next

I want to be able to make a union of rows respecting that the values ​​are unique

Example:
Merge ('a', '', 'c') with ('', 'b', '') and get ('a', 'b', 'c')

```
------------
a    b    c     
------------
a    b     c
d    e
f         g
     h
          i
j
          k
     l    n
c
     a
```

Note that ('', 'b', '') was deleted.

Merge('j', 'a', 'i')

```
------------
a    b    c     
------------
a         c
     b
d    e
f         g
     h
j    a    i
          k
     l    n
c
```

I not need merge for ecample ('', 'l','n') and ('','h','') because the 'a filed is empty' but I need merge (j, a, i) and ('','h','') and get

```
------------
a    b    c     
------------
a         c
     b
d    e
f         g
j    h    i
          k
     l    n
c
```

I'm trying to do this with a trigger, with the nex logic

if 'b' changed delete the other appearance of 'b'
if 'c' changed delete the other appearance of 'c'

But I cant do theses because I cant execute a delete into a mysql trigger, any other idea.

My goal is that the logic is executed in the database, and that if I have to call a procedure, block the update on the table, so that it can comply with the restriction of all unique rows

Comment: Hmmm...a c d, c, k a a d. This should work.

Comment: Why does row `(null,'b',null)` get merged with row `('a',null,'c')`, rather than merged with row `('f',null,'g')`, or merged with two rows `('c',null,null)` and `(null,null,'k')` to form `('c','b','k')` ?  The logic presented here must be a solution to some problem, but it's not at all clear what problem this is trying to solve. Whatever it is, my bet is that there is a simpler, more elegant solution. The design outlined in the question seems unnecessarily involved.

Comment: If you can have the same value in different columns and it should be merged away, then why not store all the values in one column and put a `UNIQUE` index on it?